# Azure SQL Server Read Scale-Out Performance

Tags: sql-server, azure

As a test, we recently started sending some queries to our read scale-out SQL Server in Azure. Our primary DB is a 40 core BC. We have noticed some pretty poor performance with queries taking up to 10x or longer time to perform than in our primary DB.

I'm assuming there isn't much I can do about this? There is no query store and it doesn't look like there is any way to tune the DB?

Answer (score 4):

We had similar issue with read scale-out replica. We used Azure SQL vCore 40 Business Critical for OLTP. After countless hours of debugging and monitoring we determined that read scale-out replica is heavely affected by the number of writes in primary.

In our case we observed high number of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait type for read queries in read scale-out replica and CPU usage up to 100%. If we switched the same read queries to the primary database CPU never went above 30% and SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD was not prevalent wait type.

Following query were showing that SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD was dominant signal wait time in read scale-out, but not in primary.

```
select * from sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
order by signal_wait_time_ms desc
```

We reduced our problem to small test case with copy of our production database, only 3  read queries, 1 heavy write query and .NET app that runs read queries in parallel. We used 12 vCore Business Critical database.

- Test 1: Execute read queries on primary. Result: ~ 1500 read queries/second, 60% CPU usage in sys.dm_db_resource_stats in primary
- Test 2: Execute read queries on read-scale out. Result: ~ 1500 read queries/second, 60% CPU usage in sys.dm_db_resource_stats in read scale-out
- Test 3: Execite write query on primary and read queries on primary. Result: ~ 1500 read queries/second, 70% CPU usage in sys.dm_db_resource_stats in primary
- Test 4: Execite write query on primary and read queries on read scale-out. Result: ~ 800 read queries/second, 100% CPU usage in sys.dm_db_resource_stats in read scale out and 10% in primary

Microsoft support and product team confirmed that there is an issue with spin locks in current replication model in Azure SQL and made temporary fix for our database - switched replication from parallel to some other model. This solved the issue for us. We are not sure if fix went to all of the databases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in this article you'll find your answer.

[Connect to a read-only replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out)

Monitoring and troubleshooting read-only replica
When connected to a read-only replica, you can access the performance metrics using the sys.dm_db_resource_stats DMV. To access query plan statistics, use the sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_exec_query_plan and sys.dm_exec_sql_text DMVs.